# Is this port of Scapy compatible with Python 3.x?

Tags: python3

I found [this attempt at poring the Scapy packet manipulator](http://src.carnivore.it/dionaea/tree/modules/python/scripts/smb/include) to Python 3.x. Has anyone had any experience using it in Python 3.x? Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, Scapy now works with Python 2.7 and 3.3 to 3.6.

Just get the latest development version from https://github.com/secdev/scapy!

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks for bringing Scapy up to date!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the attempt above, but I have my own version. Linux version is quite usable with the basic layers. See more info at https://github.com/phaethon/scapy or install as scapy-python3 from pip